# executing query having over billion rows

Tags: kdb

I have a table say 'T' in kdb which has rows over 6 billion. When I tried to execute query like this

```
 select from T where i < 10
```

it throws `wsfull expection`. Is there any way I can execute queries like this in table having large amount of data.

Answer (score 3):

```
10#T
```

The expression as you wrote it first makes a bitmap containing all of the elements where i (rownumber) < 10, which is as tall as one of your columns. It then does where (which just contains til 10) and then gets them from each row. You can save the last step with:

```
T[til 10]
```

but `10#T` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a partitioned table here, it is normally beneficial to have the partitioning column (date, int etc.) as the first item in the where clause of your query - otherwise as mentioned previously you are reading a six billion item list into memory, which will result in a 'wsfull signal for any machine with less than the requisite amount of RAM.

Bear in mind that row index starts at 0 for each partition, and is not reflective of position in the overall table. The query that you gave as an example in your question would return the first ten rows of *each* partition of table T in your database.

In order to do this without reaching your memory limit, you can try running the following (if your database is date-partitioned):

`raze{10#select from T where date=x}each date`

Comment: or, if you just want the first 10 rows of the first partition, do below:- 
10#select from T where date=first date

Comment: Yes, however as I read it the question is more about structuring queries to avoid a 'wsfull error than about making this specific query run